# LibreHardwareMonitor doesn't show GPU sensors

Tags: c#, gpu, openhardwaremonitor

Even though the Libre Hardware Monitor shows my gpu sensor data, this code below will not work only for the gpu hardware which I was interested in. It works for ALL other hardware which I also don't understand.

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data.Common;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.Remoting.Lifetime;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using LibreHardwareMonitor;
using LibreHardwareMonitor.Hardware;
using LibreHardwareMonitor.Software;
using LibreHardwareMonitor.Interop;


namespace mynamespace
{
    public class UpdateVisitor : IVisitor
    {
        public void VisitComputer(IComputer computer)
        {
            computer.Traverse(this);
        }
        public void VisitHardware(IHardware hardware)
        {
            hardware.Update();
            foreach (IHardware subHardware in hardware.SubHardware) subHardware.Accept(this);
        }
        public void VisitSensor(ISensor sensor) { }
        public void VisitParameter(IParameter parameter) { }
    }


    class Program
    {
        public class UpdateVisitor : IVisitor
        {
            public void VisitComputer(IComputer computer)
            {
                computer.Traverse(this);
            }
            public void VisitHardware(IHardware hardware)
            {
                hardware.Update();
                foreach (IHardware subHardware in hardware.SubHardware) subHardware.Accept(this);
            }
            public void VisitSensor(ISensor sensor) { }
            public void VisitParameter(IParameter parameter) { }
        }
        
        static void Monitorr()
        {
            Computer computer = new Computer
            {
                IsCpuEnabled = false,
                IsGpuEnabled = true,
                IsMemoryEnabled = false,
                IsMotherboardEnabled = false,
                IsControllerEnabled = false,
                IsNetworkEnabled = false,
                IsStorageEnabled = false,
                IsPsuEnabled = false
            };

            computer.Open();
            computer.Accept(new UpdateVisitor());

            foreach (IHardware hardware in computer.Hardware)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Hardware: {0}", hardware.Name + ":" + hardware.HardwareType);

                foreach (IHardware subhardware in hardware.SubHardware)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("\tSubhardware: {0}", subhardware.Name);

                    foreach (ISensor sensor in subhardware.Sensors)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("\t\tSensor: {0}, value: {1}", sensor.Name, sensor.Value);
                    }
                }

                foreach (ISensor sensor in hardware.Sensors)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("\tSensor: {0}, value: {1}", sensor.Name, sensor.Value);
                }
            }

            computer.Close();
        }
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            while (true)
            {
                Monitorr();// Thread.Sleep(20000000); }//adjust refresh intervals (ms)

            }
        }

    }
}
```

I couldn't find an explanation why it doesn't give gpu data. Please help. This is my first stack overflow question. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Try to change your build platform to x64
It's worked for me after searching for solution for about 5 hours...
I've found too that not all sensors from Mainboard will be achieved until you run your app with Admin Privileges.

Comment: Thank you, that solved the problem why I did not get any gpu data with LibreHardwareMonitor and missing GPU Power with OpenHardwareMonitor.